# Is it Possible to have a database table table of morethan 3000 fields

Tags: mysql, database-design, eav

I have a form of more than 3000 fields and i want to create a table without splitting it into two.

Is it okay? Or it will have problems?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Nobody is going to want to fill out a form with more than 3000 fields. It may be time to step back and see if there is another way to accomplish what you are trying to do without having a form with that many fields.

Comment: Other are optional

Comment: You have to look at the EAV model.

Comment: Study [Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html).

Answer (score 1):

3000 optional fields today; 3001 tomorrow.  You are looking at all-to-frequent `ALTER TABLE .. ADD COLUMN..`

Keep the "common" columns as MySQL columns.  Put the rest into a `JSON` string.  Be aware that it is messy and inefficient to filter or sort on data buried inside a json string.

The EAV schema pattern has, in my opinion, worse drawbacks.